# Autoincrement text field in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I hope you can help me. I'm creating an application to manage my warehouses. In my Transport Documents section I need a non-editable field that assigns an ID to any document, and I want this ID to increment automatically.

The ID is composed of a prefix (this changes based on the user loggged in) and an integer that must increment itself every time a user creates a transport document. An example will explain it better:

1) User "Mark" logged in application

```
First Transport Document ID:  MARK00001 
Second Transport Document ID: MARK00002
```

1) User "Peter" logged in application

```
First Transport Document ID:  PETE00001 
Second Transport Document ID: PETE00002
```

and so on. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Is it mandatory that this is in one textfield? It could be easier handled if there would be a simple integer for the id and a method on the Model to return a Document id by merging the user prefix with this id fields value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into the before_create callback on your record:

```
class TransportDocument << ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_friendly_id

  private
    def set_friendly_id
      # create your friendly_id here (hard to sample code without knowing your model)
      # friendly_id = current_user.name.upcase + number_of_records_plus_one_nice_format
      self.friendly_id = friendly_id
    end
end
```

If you need help assembling the friendly_name we'd need to know more about your model structure.

Comment: should be before_create most likely

Answer (score 2):

For a start I would get the highest value in a before_create filter and then generate a new number.
The User model should have something like a prefix method to get the users prefix.
Assuming that a TransportDocument belongs to a user I would do something like this:

```
class TransportDocument << ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_per_user_id

  def document_id_txt
    "#{user.prefix}#{document_id}"
  end

  private
    def set_per_user_id
      val = user.transport_documents.maximum(:document_id)
      self.document_id = val + 1
    end
end
```

I didn't test the code but it should be roughly working like that. If you need to store the prefix in the field, it would become slightly more tedious to return the actual highest value.

Setting some validation on the document_id field to ensure uniqueness per user would be a good idea too.

Comment: Thorsten's code is the way to go.  You can pad the document_id with zeros to get the specific naming convention that you are looking for in your original post.

Comment: That's not transactionally secure though, correct?  Under the right set of circumstances (same user, concurrent requests) you could end up with duplicate `document_id` (unless you set a uniqueness constraint on the DB itself).

Comment: @cailinanne: I guess you are right about such edge cases. As you say, a unique index on the DB would be a good idea. I think this would require some tricky exception handling during create. Not sure if this could be implemented in the callback queue, since it would require some retries in case there are errors.

Comment: Yeah... sounds kinda painful.  I suspect that the only 100% correct solution involves getting cozy with the details of transaction locking for the particular DB being used.  E.g. for MYSQL you need to find the maximum with a "SELECT FOR UPDATE" type approach.