# Autoincrement Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a field in my view that increment itself each time a  new document is created, my view should as  something such as:

Documents created: 2

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autoincrement text field in Rails 3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212445/autoincrement-text-field-in-rails-3-1) asked by the same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you use Rails. You can do something like this

```
Documents created: <% Document.count %>
```